# How can I handle a GET variable when there is no data being sent

Tags: php, html

On my webpage, I have 2 options, to create a new list or to edit an existing list.

If the user wishes to create a new list, a new page with a textarea comes up.

If the user wishes to edit an existing list, the lists are displayed and the user can select a list. Upon selection of the list, the user is redirected to the new list page with the text area contents already filled in.

I have this if statement in the new list page to accept input from the edit-list page:

```
$items = $_GET['items'];
if ($items){
    //get the stuff from the db and populate the text area
}
else {
    //a new empty text area
}
```

The issue is that when I try reaching this page directly from the 'create new list' option, I get an error stating that `items` is an undefined variable. 
This makes sense as the original page is not sending any data so there is nothing to get.

How can I work around this?
I can set the original page up to send a null value for `items` but I want to refrain from changing the original page. 
Is there an option to check from where the request is coming from, or an option to activate a variable only if it can be received (usable by the GET feature)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you must write/check

```
print_r($_GET)
```

if you want only check it you can use

```
if(isset($_GET["items"]){
      //it have a value
}
```

Plus:If a variable has been unset with unset(), it will no longer be set. isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been set to NULL. Also note that a NULL byte ("\0") is not equivalent to the PHP NULL constant.

Comment: @user2883071, mostly useful is: !empty($_GET["items"]) which would imply: it exists and has at least one row if it is array OR has a 'not false' value. i.e. The value it contains needs to be 'processed'.

Answer (score 2):

Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

*isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL*

```
if (isset($_GET['items'])){
    //get the stuff from the db and populate the text area
    $items = $_GET['items'];
}
```

---

`@Eugen` suggestion(check before assigning the variable:

```
$items = isset($_GET['items']) ? $_GET['items'] : null; 
if($items) { // bla bla }
```

Comment: hmm, maybe better so :-) `$items = isset($_GET['items']) ? $_GET['items'] : null; if($items) { // bla bla }`

Comment: @Eugen I added your suggestion

Comment: The error I am getting is on 
`$items = $_GET['items'];`
`Notice: Undefined index: items`.
so I changed my if statement to this:
`if (isset($_GET['items']))`
And now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You want this. You need to check if `$_GET['items']` is set, and then you can set `$items` to the result.

```
if (isset($_GET['items']) && $items = $_GET['items']){
    //get the stuff from the db and populate the text area
}
else {
    //a new empty text area
}
```

Comment: Note: This will only enter the top `if` statement if `$items` actually contains some data.